# SQL Loader get row number for current file when multiple INFILE

Tags: sql-loader

How to get the current row number for current file when processing multiple INFILEs in a single SQL Loader CTL.

RECNUM does not work here as the INFILEs are effectively treated as a single file.

Is there any native SQL Loader way of achieving this?  The workarounds considered are:

- Using Oracle sequence with max value set as number of records with cache and cycle - however for large data imports this is too slow. It also assumes that each source file contains the same number of rows
- Splitting into individual CTL files - overhead of initialising
  separate sessions is too slow when large number of files to process
- Modifying the source files to contain row number